# how do I add another search parameter in hibernate mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate and still learning the basics. I'd appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a class:

Destination

- id
- name
- longitude
- latitude

I can read destinations based on id with something like this:

```
List result = session.createQuery("from Destination as d where d.id=2").list();
```

However, I want to read destinations from database using name. I can perhaps write something like this as a query:

```
String name;  // name set somewhere else, say a function argument
List result = session.createQuery("from Destination as d where d.name LIKE %"+name).list();
```

I believe this will yield all destinations with names similar to (variable) `name`.

Is there something inbuilt in hibernate for such use cases or is there a better way to handle this ?

EDIT:
One thing that follows from my thought process is: name column on destination db table will have an index setup. Can I map this index in some way to the Destination class using hibernate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your query by concatenating strings. A more elegant solution would be to use the [Hibernate Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html).

You query would then look something like:

```
List result = session.createCriteria(Destination.class)
                  .add(Restrictions.like("name", "%" + name)
                  .list();
```